# Nexus 10 completely dead after lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

So, tried to install the new update when it flashed on my tablet.  Left it downloading, and then clicked to install.  Its now a brick. It cant boot, it has no commands.  I have tried factory reset, and nothing, it still has no command.  I dont know how to flash it, although im not dumb I could likely follow good step by step instructions, I just dont know where to start, or who to turn to.  I suspect the size of the update is what went wrong, I only have satellite internet at 512kbps.  The update was 382 meg.  My device wanted to isntall after about 20 minutes, and I can confidently say that any download of 400 meg would take about 5 hours on my connection, so idk if it tried to install something and just gave up?

Whatever.. i have a dead android on his back with an exclamation mark.  I tried Reboot, recovery, factory reset none of which worked.

Many thanks in advance for time or trouble taking to reply.

Alison

Answer (score 3):

If you are still able to boot your nexus in fastboot mode(hold down the power button and the volume down button) you can recover it quite straightforward:

- Download the desired nexus firmware from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#mantaray
- Search for a howto flash your nexus 10 via fastboot. Something like this if using windows: http://nexus10root.com/nexus-10-unroot/how-to-unrootunbrick-nexus-10-factory-firmware/

**Flashing through fastboot requires an unlocked bootloader - unlocking will remove all your userdata!**

If any questions appear just ask ;)

Comment: Ty! :)  I downloaded the factory image for my model, and once I had directed the 'nexus root toolkit' to the zip file, it did it all for me :)  Im so relieved! :)

I have since been able to get the lollipop update too and all appears to be working fine :) 

many thanks